# sendmail process seems to hang

Tags: centos, sendmail

I got a centos machine that I am configuring send mail for. It has been working for the past couple of weeks. But around last week suddenly the sendmail stopped sending emails. var/log/maillog doesn't show any obvious errors. I tried the suggestions in the following post about changing the daemon option to not include the localhost as per post here:

[Where to check log of sendmail?](https://serverfault.com/questions/59602/where-to-check-log-of-sendmail)

but here is the thing: I got another identical server with the localhost included in the daemon option and that one is working fine.

I found that if I reboot the sendmail service it can start the queued mail messages.

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the symptoms?  When the issue occurs, does it stop sending all emails? Or just stop processing deferred/queued messages?  Is the daemon listening on port 25 during this issue?  What happens if you manually try connecting to the host via a telnet test?

Comment: The symptom is just that the mail doesn't get sent, all messages does not get sent. It seems to hold it in queue/deferred and that's it. The daemon is listening on port 25.

Comment: What happens when you telnet to the system while the issue is occurring and try sending a message?  How far in the SMTP transaction does it get?