# Ubuntu Server; Email from PHP stopped working

Tags: php, email, ubuntu-14.04

I currently have a VPS server running Ubuntu. I have used this server for a while and have was using the built in mail function for PHP. Now for reason, emails are no longer sent. According to PHP, the mail sends correctly but now it does not. This issue occrus with both a standard PHP mail() function and SMTP. Again, it worked for a while; I did not change anything and I cannot figure out why it is not working now. I have looked around the Internet and found PostFix, however my VPS hosts multiple domains so PostFix is not an option. Is this something on my host's end thats not right or is their something wrong with my server? Thank you.

Comment: Sending mail from command line works?

Comment: @ElzoValugi I do not know. I have never tried that. I will look into it and get back to you.

Comment: If it works then is something inside php or your script.

Comment: @ElzoValugi I tried sending the email via a command line and that did not work.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @ElzoValugi No, no errors. According to PHP everything is normal.

Comment: This does not seem like a PHP issue. Check the /var/log/mail.log for errors

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/questions/59602/where-to-check-log-of-sendmail

Comment: @ElzoValugi Ok so I checked my log and did find something interesting. Every address, whether to my domain mail, gmail, or phone carrier all come up with similar errors. Here is an example (with my email omitted): Jul 12 16:26:58 server1 postfix/smtp[11784]: ED1932A820CB: to=<me@mywebsite.com>, relay=none, delay=6.8, delays=0.62/0/6.2/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx2.zoho.com[165.254.168.50]:25: No route to host)

Comment: I should add that zoho.com was only the email host I use for my domain; emails are not sending to other hosts either.

Comment: Your service provider is blocking outgoing email from your server. Contact them for assistance.

Comment: @MichaelHampton By service provider, you mean my VPS company correct?

Comment: That's right, whoever provides the VPS service to you.

Comment: Thank you MichaelHampton and ElzoValugi. I will contact my hosting provider and hopefully I can get this resolved. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: I had same problem than i tried this page solution and it was worked for me. http://serverfault.com/questions/119105/setup-ubuntu-server-to-send-mail you can also try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions, it appears that their is an issue with my host. Unfortunately, it has been a few weeks since I reported the problem to them and they have not fixed it yet :(